# AngularJS outputting Javascript in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, morris.js

Hi good people of stack overflow..

I am trying to make a directive in angular that outputs javascript that I'll use to draw a morris chart.  So far I've been having a tough time.  Here's the code:

area-chart.js:

```
angular.module('areaChart', ['ui.bootstrap']).directive('areaChart', function() {
var directive = {};
directive.templateUrl = directivePath + '/charts/area-chart.html';
directive.restrict = 'EA';
directive.scope = {
    dealership: "=",
    chartdata: "="
};

directive.controller = function($scope) {
    $scope.ykeys = function() {
        var ykeys = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.chartData, function(d,k) {
            if(k != 'period') { ykeys.push(k); }
        });
        return "'" + ykeys.join("','") + "'";
    }
}

return directive;
});
```

And, area-chart.html

```
<script>
Morris.Area({
    element: 'area-chart-fuckyou',
    xkey: 'period',
    ykeys: [{{ ykeys }}],
    labels: [{{ ykeys }}],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    pointSize: 2,
    resize: true,
    data: 'fuckyou' 
});
</script>
```

I get an unexpected token '{' error any time i try to use angular substitution in the outputted javascript.  So, where I try to inject `{{ykeys}}` it throws the error.  I've tried changing `{{ykeys}}` to include the full string that I'd want in there IE having it return `['key1','key2']` and all combinations thereof.  I guess I don't understand what the order of operations is for angular.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why not have the directive controller or link function call `Morris.Area` directly?!

Comment: Now I have other questions but I'll put them in a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `link` function that will do the chart initialization

```
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs){
  new Morris.Area({
      element: element, //here you can attach direct element
      data: scope.data,
      ykey: scope.ykeys()
      labels: scope.ykeys(),
      hideHover: 'auto',
      pointSize: 2,
      resize: true,
      data: 'fuckyou' 

  });
}
```